# Django formset factory ChoiceField causes is_valid to fail and return false

Tags: django, forms, radio-button, formset

I'm using a formset factory to generate a dynamic set of form elements. I'd like to add a set of dynamic radio buttons and dropdown menus, but when I use ChoiceField, the search.is_valid() evaluates to false. I'm sure I'm doing something obviously wrong, but I can't find it.

```
...
    search_formset = formset_factory(SearchForm, extra=num_extra_charts)

    # data to initialize forms
    data = {
        'form-TOTAL_FORMS': str(num_extra_charts),
        'form-INITIAL_FORMS': str(num_extra_charts),
        'form-MAX_NUM_FORMS': '',
    }
    self.search_forms = search_formset(get_request or data)
    if self.search_forms.is_valid():

...

class SearchForm(forms.Form):

    ORDERS = [('ASC', 'ASC'),
          ('DESC', 'DESC')]

    search = forms.CharField(label='',
                         max_length=250,
                         required=False,
                         widget=forms.TextInput(
                             attrs={'placeholder': 'ex. Matt Damon AND war'}),
                         )

    property = forms.CharField(label='',
                           max_length=250,
                           required=False,
                           widget=forms.TextInput(
                               attrs={'placeholder': 'Property Filter'}),
                           )

    limit = forms.CharField(label='',
                        max_length=250,
                        required=False,
                        widget=forms.TextInput(
                            attrs={'placeholder': 'Limit - Default: 25'}),
                        )

    orders = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(choices=ORDERS))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
self.search_forms = search_formset(get_request or data)
```

This is unusual. It means that the formset is always bound.

Normally you would have

```
self.search_forms = search_formset(get_request or None)
```

Since you don not have `required=False`, that means that you must provide the values for the `orders` fields in the form data, otherwise you will get an error.

Comment: Yea, I realized that about 5 minutes after posting. However, from what I understand, the formset has to have the initial values in data or you'll get a management error.

Comment: You only need the management form values if the formset is *bound*.  If the form is unbound (e.g. `self.search_formset(None)` or `self.search_formset()`) then you won't get the management error. See the docs on [bound and unbound forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/forms/#bound-and-unbound-form-instances).

Comment: The key was that I added that data variable before I realized I needed `{{ management_form }}` in my html template. Then I never removed it because everything worked. Thanks, this is much cleaner/easier to understand now.